# Popup window in MVC5?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi i have two fields in my view CustomerName (TextBox) and ContactPerson(dropdown) and i have one add button near to ContactPerson which is mentioned in the below image.

[image]

If i type and select the CustomerName the CustomerName related ContactPerson will load automatically in contact person dropdown. Suppose if the contact person is not list means i will click that Plus(+) button it will open he pop-up window to add the Customer related contact person. The pop-up window  which is mention in the below image.

[image]

Now my issue is if i select the customername and and click the + button means it will pass the customername in the pop-up window. But here it passing the CustomerID instead of customer name which is mention in the image.

Before I kept the Cistomer Name as dropdown  so when i click the + button it will pass the value . which is mention in the below image.

[image]

Code which i kept as dropdown.

**View Code**

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerID, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a Customer", new { @class = "form-control required", type = "text" })
```

**Jquery Code**

```
         $("#modal-opener").click(function () {
            debugger
            var Customerid = $("#CustomerID").val();
            $('#customer').val(Customerid).val();
             $('#customername').text($('#CustomerID option:selected').text());
            $("#dialog-modal").dialog("open");
        });
```

Now i change that dropdown as autocomplete textbox for user friendly.. In this i cant able to pass the value as text . it pass the value as id  format to pop-up window which is mention in the second image.

My view model

```
public Nullable<System.Guid> CustomerID { get; set; }
public string CustomerName { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.Guid> CustomerContactID { get; set; }
....
```

My View

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => Model.CustomerName, new { @class = "control-label" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.CustomerName, new { @class = "form-control required" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.CustomerID)

@Html.Label("Contact Person", new { @class = "control-label" })
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="modal-opener" style="float: right; Width: 28px; height: 28px; ">+</a>

<div id="dialog-modal" title="Add New Contact Person" style="display:none">
    <div class="box-body">
        <div>Customer Name</div>
        <div id="customername"></div>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CustomerID, new { id = "customer" })
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactPerson)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ContactPerson, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContactPerson)
        ....
        <div class="box-footer">
            <input id="Button1" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Save" onclick="SaveContact()" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerContactID, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a ContactPerson", new { @class = "form-control required", type = "text", id = "CustomerContactID" })
```

My jquery code for opening the modal

```
$("#modal-opener").click(function () {
    debugger
    var Customerid = $("#CustomerID").val();                          
    $('#customer').val(Customerid).val();                          
    $('#customername').text(Customerid).text();              
    $("#dialog-modal").dialog("open");
});
```

When i Click the + button it will pass the CustomerID instead of customer name. This is the issue. Anyone help me to resolve this issue. I want to pass the customer name but here it passing the  customer ID in pop-up window. Any one help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Is the `CustomerName` textbox in the main form an autocomplete control?

Comment: Yes Stephen customer name is auto complete textbox.I kept that field as auto complete textbox

Comment: Then you have not given us enough info. `var Customerid = $("#CustomerID").val();` return the value of the textbox so `$('#customer').val(Customerid)` and `$('#customername').text(Customerid)` set those elements to that value (adding `.val()` and `.text()` respectively is pointless and does nothing). What does `console.log('#CustomerID').text());` return?

Comment: Now it passing the value as ID now i want to pass that as name. Then did you ask me to try Console.log('CustomerID').text()); stephen..

Comment: Yes, what does `console.log('#CustomerID').text());` output in the browser console - is it the value you want? - your clearly using a jquery plugin but have not even told us what that is so its impossible to help you any further.

Comment: Ok  i have a check and let you know

Comment: Stephen its not working when i give console.log('#CustomerID').text()); it didnt open the pop-up window too. Before i  kept customer name as dropdown so   i used this                                                                                $('#customername').text($('#CustomerID option:selected').text());                              to pass the Value as text now after changing the dropdown  to textbox i can able to pass the value as id i cant able to pass as name..

Comment: No one can help you unless you give the relevant information - what plugin are you using? How are you attaching it? etc

Comment: Yes stephen i want that value  wait i will show you with clear example

Comment: Stephen check my updated code

Comment: <link href="~/Areas/Sales/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="~/Areas/Sales/Scripts/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Areas/Sales/Scripts/jquery-ui.1.10.4min.js"></script>          These are the plugins im using..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115164/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-susan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your using a jQuery-ui autocomplete plugin for the `CustomerID` property which hides the textbox that `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.CustomerID, ...)` generates and replaces it with its own html. You need to use the values from the plugin to get both the value and display text. You have not shown how you have attached the plugin, but assuming its

```
$('#CustomerID').autocomplete({
    ....
});
```

then you can add a global variables and in the `select` event, set the values which you can then pass to the modal

```
var customerID;
var customerName;

$('#CustomerID').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetVisitCustomer", "VisitorsForm")',
            datatype: "json",
            data: {
                Areas: 'Sales',
                term: request.term
            },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (val, item) {
                    return {
                        label: val.Name,
                        value: val.ID,
                    }                                     
                }))
            }
        })
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        customerID = ui.item.value;
        customerName = ui.item.label;
    }
});
```

and then the code to open the dialog

```
 $("#modal-opener").click(function () {                         
    $('#customer').val(CustomerID);                          
    $('#customername').text(customerName);              
    $("#dialog-modal").dialog("open");
})
```

Comment: [![enter image description here][4]][4]
  [4]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/HCal7.jpg See this image stephen . In this image i gave Customer Name and click the + button means it open the pop-up window with the customer name which i select in the CustomerName Field . But If i didnt Select the Customer Name(CustomerName is Empty) and Click the + button means it didnt open the popup window it showing error

Comment: [![enter image description here][4]][4]
  [4]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/HCal7.jpg See this image. I have Select the Customer Name and press the + button it will display the customer name which i select in the Customer Name field in pop-up window. But if I didnt slect the Customer Name empty and click the + buttom means it didnt open the pop-up window it showing error

Comment: Then you need to handle the case where a customer name is not selected, for example - `$("#modal-opener").click(function () { if (!$(CustomerID).val()) { return; } else { ...... $("#dialog-modal").dialog("open"); } });`